# Html 100% header responsive width

Tags: css, image, header

How do I create a full width website header that adjusts to browser screen?

Slider example: http://dandywebsolution.com/skdslider/

I want to create a single image header with full 100% width you can click above link and hit (ctrl + -) you can see the image adjust with the browser zoom out.

Comment: CTRL +/- just scales your font size - it doesn't change the size of the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, add this:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ELeHomuZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you use the image.

As background-image, do:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(whatever.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If its an img-tag, do:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
}

#headerImg {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You have to set width to 100% in EVERY element which contains the header up to body/html.